# Seleccionar contenido de primer elemento hermano para capturar su contenido con Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, datatables

Estoy teniendo problemas para seleccionar un elemento hermano del padre mediante `Jquery`.

Tengo una tabla, donde uno de los datos es un Id que se identifica cada fila. En esa misma fila, tengo unos botones para desarrollar una serie de acciones. Lo que necesito es que, al pulsar el botón de una fila, saque el valor de la celda de la columna Id mediante `Jquery` para luego pasarla por `AJAX` a `PHP` y de ahí me haga la búsqueda de los datos del usuario con ese Id que capturé.

He probado de todo y no hay manera, ni nada similar en el foro que yo vea.

Adjunto foto, a ver si podéis darme una pista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resumen: al pulsar botón azul debo sacar el contenido de la celda de esa misma fila para guardarla en una variable.

Añado la foto que decía en los comentarios:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí es donde están los botones, y no veo forma de enlazar el valor de { 'data': 'ID' } en el atributo "data-empleado" para que en cada iteración, cada botón tenga su valor asociado a su fila.

Gracias!

Comment: Creo que faltan detalles para que tu pregunta sea clara. Sin embargo trataré de darte una alternativa en la sección de respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes la opción de agregar al botón el atributo **data-empleado** al construir la vista que te muestra el listado de empleados y asignarle el id del empleado, *mismo que tienes en la columna ID*.

Posteriormente, capturas el valor de **data-empleado** a través de `jQuery` y lo usas para lo que necesites.

Te dejo datos de ejemplo, pero debes adaptarlo a tu código.

```js
//Al hacer click en el botón
$('.botonVer').on('click', function(){
  //Se obtiene el valor del atributo data-empleado. this hace referencia al botón que pulses.
  let idEmpleado = $(this).data('empleado');
  //Luego puedes usarlo para lo que necesites
  console.log('id del empleado: ' + idEmpleado);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      7
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="botonVer ..." data-empleado="7">
        Buscar
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      8
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="botonVer ..." data-empleado="8">
        Buscar
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      9
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="botonVer ..." data-empleado="9">
        Buscar
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Es justamente lo que necesito, que cuando pulse el botón de la lupa, sepa a qué fila estoy pulsando en base a al Id de esa fila. Eso funciona si pongo los valores a mano, pero son datos dinámicos que enlazan a bases de datos y veo cómo poner el valor al atributo de forma dinámica (que en cada vuelta de bucle le asigne el valor Id correspondiente para luego poder elegirlo). Tengo las columnas de los botones montadas en 'defaultContent' de datatables, subo foto al mensaje de inicio para que se aprecie.

Comment: El problema es que estas asociando el evento a un id, el cual se entiende es unico, por ende te deberia funcionar solo con la primera fila de la tabla, en este caso para que no se asocie al id y te genere ese conflicto, lo que te recomiendo es que el evento caputure la data asociada a la clase y no al id

Comment: @CamiloKent , en realidad el Id no se refiere al HTML, si no a una columna que viene de una base de datos por tanto el Id es un número único que se pone al principio de cada fila, como se ve en la primera foto de la tabla. Quiero acceder a ese valor, a esa celda, desde el botón de la misma fila y que este sepa, al clicarlo, que corresponde al Id de esa fila.

Answer (score 0):

AL final me han echado un cable desde otro lado y ya tengo la solución que comparto. Era así:

```
this.parentElement.parentElement.firstChild.innerHTML;
```

Con eso logro acceder al valor de cada Id y enviarlo mediante AJAX para que se procese en una consulta a BBDD y devuelva los datos del Id correspondiente.

Comment: Qué bueno que hayas logrado darle solución a tu problema con código nativo. De cualquier forma, con jQuery sería así: 

`$(this).parents("tr").first().html();`